# Qt Reading data from socket

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, client

I'm trying to implement a TCP/IP client using Qt 5.7. Currently I have these line in my code

```
_socket = new QTcpSocket();
_socket->connectToHost(hostIp,_port);
if(_socket->waitForConnected(2000)){
        qDebug() << "Connected!";
        qDebug() << _socket->peerAddress();
}
connect( _socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(readTcpData()) );


}

void eegClient::readTcpData()
{
    QByteArray data = _socket->readAll();
}
```

I tried testing this code with a simply python server:

```
import socket
import sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 10003)
sock.bind(server_address)


sock.listen(1)

while True:
    print >> sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
    (connection, client_address) = sock.accept()
    try:
        print >> sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address
        while True:
            if 1:
                BUFFER = "a string"
                connection.sendall(BUFFER)
            else:
                print >> sys.stderr, 'no more data from', client_address
                break
    finally:

        # Clean up the connection

        connection.close()
```

The problem is that my code never emit 'readyRead' signal. When I checked it with a simple python client, it worked and read the information so I don't think the problem is with the server. Also, the lines  qDebug() << "Connected!";qDebug() << _socket->peerAddress();
Do print the right address and the server gets the connection. Trying to write to the server also fails, and bytesAvailable always returns 0.
What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: Well, your code works for me on the 127.0.0.1. Maybe there's a firewall problem?

Comment: Also, I'd connect the readyRead before actually starting a network connection.

Comment: Thanks, with the python client it worked and I've checked the firewall - nothing special. Tried moving the connect, not helping so far :-(

Comment: Could you post a full text of your eegClient somewhere like at pastebin? It feels like your problem lies somewhere outside this piece of code.